# SagePay VPS Protocol 4.00 Server Integration - VPSSignature not matching

Tags: vb.net, http-post, opayo

Please see the transaction post

```
VPSProtocol=4.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=Vendorname
&VendorTxCode=324234906133500
&Amount=20.00
&Currency=GBP
&Description=Payment
&BillingSurname=Jo
&BillingFirstnames=Test
&BillingAddress1=43
&BillingCity=Ash
&BillingPostCode=Asd234
&BillingCountry=GB
&BillingPhone=323-8412233
&CustomerEMail=test@test.com
&DeliverySurname=Jo
&DeliveryFirstnames=Test
&DeliveryAddress1=43
&DeliveryCity=Ash
&DeliveryPostCode=Asd234
&DeliveryCountry=GB
&DeliveryPhone=323-8412233
&AllowGiftAid=0
&ApplyAVSCV2=1
&Apply3DSecure=1
&Profile=LOW
&VendorData=Rent
&NotificationURL=https://testpage/notificationpage.aspx
```

Please see the Transaction Post Response below

```
Status: OK
VendorTxCode: 324234906133500
VPSTxId: {8652345E-5B25-49F1-DD23-1B9CCC2B6545}
Security Key: AZFE2KOSDS
VPSSignature: N135C007EF1643ABE44CAC12EBD9ED43
StatusDetail: 0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.
TxAuthNo: 34234532
AVSCV2: SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY
AddressResult: NOTMATCHED
PostCodeResult: NOTMATCHED
CV2Result: MATCHED
GiftAid: 0
3DSecureStatus: OK
CAVV: Y2c2ZVVBeTRvTUVwVGtpaGVMdzk=
AddressStatus:
PayerStatus:
CardType: VISA
Last4Digits: 0006
DeclineCode: 00
ExpiryDate: 0123
BankAuthCode: 999777
Surcharge: 0.40
FraudResponse:
ACSTransID: 490ead88-8dc8-4ac4-b40a-fbe1f8a95182
DSTransID: 3f06865c-33c1-462c-956d-01f4c55114b5
SchemeTraceID: Wkv0Jq8QEYu4DupyW0gG}s2~}N2K~U+7LAMYCVU0vXt2uH0prPJCpY6
```

**The Issue is VPSSignature is not matching after computing the MD5 signature**

```
VPSTxId+VendorTxCode+Status+TxAuthNo+VendorName+AVSCV2+SecurityKey+AddressResult+ PostCodeResult+CV2Result+GiftAid+3DSecureStatus+CAVV+AddressStatus+PayerStatus+CardType+ Last4Digits+DeclineCode+ExpiryDate+FraudResponse+BankAuthCode+ACSTransID+DSTransID+SchemeTraceID
```

SERVER Integration POST URL: https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp

Answer (score 1):

Have you validated your code that builds the signature to be compared against VPSSignature in the Post response? Are they salting the MD5? Are you feeding it the exact payload? I fed your Post into an MD5 generator and I got 79dda36adfdc796412ab0fa77ca67380 instead of N135C007EF1643ABE44CAC12EBD9ED43 .